# Breaking up CSS into blocks with regex

Tags: css, ruby, regex

I have a stylesheet:

```
a,b,c { stuff
        lots of it
}

b { more stuff }

.test { even more }
```

I want a regular expression to break it up into each of the three parts, separating from '}' to '}' should work alright for my needs (except the first case obviously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9, you could

```
result = subject.split(/(?<=\})/)
```

i.e., split the string at a position following a `}`. Ruby 1.8 doesn't support lookbehind assertions, though, so it won't work there. And of course you'll be running into problems with nested braces, but you said that this shouldn't be a problem with your data.

In Ruby 1.8 (can't try it here), the following should work:

```
result = subject.split(/(\})/)
```

although now the closing braces won't be part of the matched elements anymore. So `test {a} test2 {b}` will be split into `test {a`, `}`, `test2 {b`, `}` plus an empty string.

Comment: Seems like a regular split('}') is the easiest way to go. Not sure about 1.9 on my host.

Answer (score 0):

It may be inappropriate in your case, but you could use a CSS parser to split your CSS file by tokens and operate on them independently and harmlessly.

1. [css_parser](http://code.google.com/p/ruby-css-parser/) (with [this guide](http://railstalk.com/2010/1/5/ruby-css-parser));
2. [CSSPool](http://csspool.rubyforge.org/) (I recommend this one just because you only need to obtain certain selectors from your CSS; this one is like a SAX parser for CSS).

Comment: The main reason I have to tokenize is because I need to leave anything that contains a body selector out of the equation. This would include a line like a, li, body, html { ... }. Not sure if these gems would make life easier or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
.scan(/.+?\}/m)
```